# Joining.csv file and .shp of georeferenced points

Tags: shapefile, point, georeferencing, attribute-joins, csv

I have georeferenced a map and saved a selection of some points on the map. These points are cities of departure and arrival and I want to join the .shp with a and excel .csv with the information of the migration of my individuals to represent their way.

-If I join on my .shp (the selected points and the origin cities on .csv) I only get 15 out of 40 lines as many individuals started their trip from the same city

-If I join on my .csv I have a complete table attributes. I save a selection and want to open it as .shp but I only have three extensions (.dbf, .prj, .qpj)

How can I get a complete joined table attributes between a .cvs of 40 items and a .shp of 15 items and make sure the items are georeferenced on my map?

Comment: Which software do you use?